# I have upgraded to mysql 5.7. but the service does not start

Tags: mysql

I have upgraded from mysql 5.5 to 5.7.10 but the service does not start.
I try to enter `systemctl enable mysqld.service and systemctl start mysqld.service or systemctl enable mariadb.service and systemctl start mariadb.service` and i keep getting the output

> Job for mysqld.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysqld.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

Any help to what i am doing wrong ?

Comment: This question is not really about sw development. DBAs, sysadmins, would be better positioned to provide a reasonable answer. You should check the logs listed in the error message.

Answer (score 1):

install "mysql-devel" package because it provide the shared and necessary libraries if you want to compile.
    sudo dnf install mysql-devel
and then start the mysql server